# Git diff HEAD before ever commiting

Tags: git

I'm quite new to Git. My question concern the execution of the `git diff HEAD` command before ever commiting. I know that HEAD doesnt exist until I had commited something. So how do I do to get the difference between working directory & the initial state of the repo.

I know that this command gives the difference between working directory & the index (Stage):

```
git diff
```

And that the following command gives the difference between the index & the repo:

```
git diff --cached
```

Comment: I don't get it: is it a newly created empty repo?

Comment: Exactly! a fresh repo

Comment: The `git diff` of an empty repository with the (modified) working directory is simply the contents of the working directory... `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat` should show you your entire working directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do a `git commit --allow-empty` without adding anything if you you really really want to diff the first "real" commit that adds things.

Comment: I guess that's the only solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To have a HEAD to compare against, you can create an empty commit by `git commit --allow-empty` immediately after `git init`.

Comment: Immediately after `git init` means that it comes before `git add`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually my initial commit is simply a README file.  That forces me to create a README and I can also check that my push to remotes are working.  My first `real` commit of actual code follows that one, and, so, the regular `git diff` at this point works as you're intending it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `git status`?  If you have a newly-initialized repository with no commits, there will not be much of interest yet.

You can use `git add .` to slurp everything in the current directory to the staging index and then commit.

After your first commit, you will be able to see any further changes using `git diff`.